# 3 level ExpandableListView Android

Tags: android, xamarin, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have come across a few questions on SO regarding the same and have tried them.

I can show upto 2 levels in the expandable list, but I cannot show the third level when I click the second level.

I have tried something like so :-

ParentView (First Level)

```
public class ParentView : BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {
        public static int FIRST_LEVEL_COUNT = 6;
        public static int SECOND_LEVEL_COUNT = 4;
        public static int THIRD_LEVEL_COUNT = 10;
        private Context context;



        public ParentView(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public ParentView()
        {
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return childPosition;
        }


        public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return childPosition;
        }



        public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var SecondLevelexplv = new CustExpListview(Application.Context);
            SecondLevelexplv.SetAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter(context));
            SecondLevelexplv.SetGroupIndicator(null);
            return SecondLevelexplv;
        }

        public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
        {
            return 3;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
        {
            return groupPosition;
        }
        public override int GroupCount
        {
            get
            {
                return 5;
            }
        }

        public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
        {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var tv = new TextView(Application.Context)
            {
                Text = "->FirstLevel",
            };
            tv.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);
            tv.SetPadding(10, 7, 7, 7);

            return tv;
        }

        public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override bool HasStableIds
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```

CustExpListView

```
public class CustExpListview : ExpandableListView
{

public CustExpListview(Context context) : base(context)
{
}

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(999999, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(999999, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
    OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

SecondLevelAdapter

```
   public class SecondLevelAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
public static int THIRD_LEVEL_COUNT = 10;
private Context context;
private readonly ParentView parentView;

public SecondLevelAdapter(Context context) 
{
    this.context = context;
}

public SecondLevelAdapter(ParentView parentView)
{
this.parentView = parentView;
}

public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
{
    return groupPosition;
}

public override int GroupCount
{
    get
    {
        return 5;
    }
}



public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
{
    return groupPosition;
}


public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var tv = new TextView(Application.Context)
    {
        Text = "-->Second"
    };
    tv.SetPadding(12, 7, 7, 7);
    tv.SetBackgroundColor(Color.GreenYellow);

    return tv;
}



public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return childPosition;
}

public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return childPosition;
}



public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var tv = new TextView(Application.Context)
    {
        Text = "third"
    };
    tv.SetPadding(18, 5, 5, 5);
    tv.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);

    return tv;
}


public override int GetChildrenCount(int ChildPosition)
{
    return 4;
}


public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return true;
}

public override bool HasStableIds
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

What I noticed is that the `GetChildView()` in the `SecondLevelAdapter` is never called though the `GetGroup()` is called. I actually want to expand the list upto 4 levels, but I am stuck at the 3rd level itself.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 4-level expandable list on mobile? I think you might rethink your design to look more mobile friendly like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/images/patterns-md-stacked.png).

Comment: @R.Zagórski well the customer has that kind of requirement which cannot be compromised on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is for every row of `-->Second` it is a whole `ExpandableListView`,which contains 5 Groups. And as the height of the current parent group won't expand automatically for the child `ExpandableListView`. You can't see the opened children list: `third`.

To Fix the problem, there are a few changes to be made:

1. Change the `GroupCount` of `SecondLevelAdapter` from 5 to 1:

   ```
   public override int GroupCount
   {
       get
       {
           //return 5;
           return 1;//Change GroupCount to 1
       }
   }
   ```
2. You need to change the height of every second level ExpandableListView manually. This can be done by implementing `GroupExpand` and `GroupCollapse` events:

   ParentView.cs:

   ```
   public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
       var SecondLevelexplv = new CustExpListview(Application.Context);
       SecondLevelexplv.SetAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter(context));
       SecondLevelexplv.SetGroupIndicator(null);
       SecondLevelexplv.GroupExpand += SecondLevelexplv_GroupExpand;
       SecondLevelexplv.GroupCollapse += SecondLevelexplv_GroupCollapse;
       return SecondLevelexplv;
   }

   private void SecondLevelexplv_GroupCollapse(object sender, ExpandableListView.GroupCollapseEventArgs e)
   {
       AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 70);
       (sender as CustExpListview).LayoutParameters = lp;
   }

   private void SecondLevelexplv_GroupExpand(object sender, ExpandableListView.GroupExpandEventArgs e)
   {
       //expand the group and the height is the `children count` * `unit height`
       AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 70 * 5);
       (sender as CustExpListview).LayoutParameters = lp;
   }
   ```

Thus, it will work correctly:

[image]