# Xamarin.Android multiple generic lists in RecyclerView

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

**Situation: I'm having a list of countries. Within this lists I'll have a list of cities. I want to represent a cardview for each country that shows the cities.**

[image: Carview1]

[image: Cardview2]

Country.cs

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Flag { get; set; }
    public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

City.cs

```
public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    public IList<Country> Countries = new List<Country>();
    public IList<City> CitiesBelgium = new List<City>();
    public IList<City> CitiesGermany = new List<City>();

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    CountryAdapter countryAdapter;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        PopulateList(); //this will populate the desired lists in this example

        recyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        countryAdapter = new CountryAdapter(Countries);
        recyclerView.SetAdapter(countryAdapter);
    }
}
```

CountryAdapter.cs

```
public class CountryAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    IList<Country> countries;
    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return countries.Count; }
    }

    public CountryAdapter(IList<Country> countries)
    {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        CountryViewHolder vh = holder as CountryViewHolder;
        vh.Id.Text = countries[position].CountryId.ToString();
        vh.Description.Text = countries[position].Description;
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                Inflate(Resource.Layout.CountryCardView, parent, false);
        CountryViewHolder vh = new CountryViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }
}
```

CountryViewHolder.cs

```
public class CountryViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView Id { get; private set; }
    public TextView Description { get; private set; }

    public CountryViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
    {
        Id = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewId);
        Description = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDescription);
    }
}
```

This is working and I get a cardview for each country. **But what is the best way to get the list of cities in the cardview of the country?**

[image: Working example]

In Xamarin.Forms you can group items. I don't think this is possible with RecyclerView? Example: https://dzone.com/articles/xamarin-forms-grouping-enabled-listview

Comment: Hi, hope this helps! 1. thing: Currently, you are setting the ItemCount to "2" - for each of your countries - but this mean, that you will only draw "2" cells. You need this to include both "header/country" cells, and "city" cells.

Comment: 2. override "GetItemViewType(int position)" and define wheter it is a Header or a City (indicate with an integer or enum)

Comment: 3. In "RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)" you will create the viewholder based on the viewtype.

Comment: 4. in "OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)" you cast to Header or City (based on the type of the holder). And then you populate the holder with data.

Comment: 4.1: but the data you put in is like: "cell at pos 0" -> Country name belgium... "cell at pos 2" -> City data Ghent... "cell at pos 3" -> Country name Germany...

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: But it needs to be a flat list or can I use the same structure of my classes?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm having a list of countries. Within this lists I'll have a list of cities. I want to represent a cardview for each country that shows the cities.

You could use [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) to implement this feature:

> A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling two-level list. This differs from the ListView by allowing two levels: groups which can individually be expanded to show its children. The items come from the ExpandableListAdapter associated with this view.

Here is the [example](https://github.com/away168/ExpandableListView).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think this will help me a lot. But can you also implement more levels than only 2? In my real world application I need 3 levels of data. Grouping - detail - and a list of a the detail.

Comment: @JeffreyM, this example is 3 levels of data, :).

Comment: @JeffreyM, and you could refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627161/3-level-expandablelistview-android/42688823#42688823, hope this ca help you.